# Drill Core Stratigraphic Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, environment

I am a student looking for data for a GIS project to use in modeling subsurface lithology in ArcScene.

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding where I can find spatially-organized stratigraphic data including lithology for bore-holes?

It does not matter what country. As long as I have quality data, I am happy to work with it no matter the source.

Comment: For which country/study area?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  It does not matter what country.  As long as I have quality data, I am happy to work with it no matter the source.

Answer (score 3):

IHS has several systems that have the information you need, but most of them are targeted to large corporate customers.

You can access many of them through your school, as I know they have agreements to license those systems to universities.
I know geology and petroleum engineering schools in Canada use them.

https://www.ihs.com/products/petra-geological-analysis.html

Answer (score 2):

To get links to csv-files containing lithologies quickly, try

https://pangaea.de/?q=lithology

These datasets are small, and they stem from academic projects.

You can also get an impression on how lithology data were used to create models of the subsurface: For Germany, try http://geotis.de (focus on geothermal energy - relatively shallow wells, but many deep ones, too), for the world try the online-gis http://www.onegeology.org; for USA, try http://seamless.usgs.gov.

Answer (score 1):

The British Geological Survey provides free online access (through a [web GIS](http://mapapps.bgs.ac.uk/geologyofbritain/home.html?)) to [scans](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/data/boreholescans/home.html) of over a million borehole records.

> Borehole records are produced from a geologist's or surveyor's observations of the rock core extracted from the ground. It typically includes locality, lithological descriptions with depth and thickness.

An example of a scan is:

[BGS ID: 699361 : BGS Reference: NY86NE25](http://scans.bgs.ac.uk/sobi_scans/boreholes/699361/images/12446545.html)